# thinkpad_acpi disabling brightness events

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, brightness, acpi, backlight

After installing routine updates, my keyboard brightness controls, wireless on/off, and other controls have stopped working. Interestingly, the 'lock' key still works. 
I have looked at a few other similar questions, but they don't seem to be too similar.
I am running a Lenovo T430

Here is dmesg ouput:

```
dmesg

    [   20.666040] thinkpad_acpi: ThinkPad ACPI Extras v0.25
    [   20.666042] thinkpad_acpi: http://ibm-acpi.sf.net/
    [   20.666043] thinkpad_acpi: ThinkPad BIOS G7ET94WW (2.54 ), EC unknown
    [   20.666045] thinkpad_acpi: Lenovo ThinkPad T430s, model 2352CTO
    [   20.666334] thinkpad_acpi: detected a 16-level brightness capable ThinkPad
    [   20.666426] thinkpad_acpi: radio switch found; radios are enabled
    [   20.666503] thinkpad_acpi: This ThinkPad has standard ACPI backlight brightness control, supported by the ACPI video driver
    [   20.666504] thinkpad_acpi: Disabling thinkpad-acpi brightness events by default...
```

__

Also, sys/class/backlight directory is empty.

Thanks for the help.